# A proof of the scaling/shift property of variance

Tags: probability, proof-verification, random-variables

I would like to show that $Var(aX + b) = a^2 Var(X)$ using a different proof from my book

> Let $Y = aX + b$
>
> $Var(Y) = E(Y^2) - E[Y]^2$
>
> = $E[(aX + b)^2] - E(aX + b)^2$
>
> = $E[(a^2 X^2 + b^2 + 2abX] - (a\mu+b)^2$
>
> = $a^2E(X^2) + b^2 + 2abE[X] - (a^2\mu^2 + b^2 + 2ab\mu)$
>
> = $a^2E(X^2) + b^2 + 2ab\mu - (a^2E[X]^2 + b^2 + 2ab\mu)$
>
> = $a^2E[X^2] - a^2E[X]^2$
>
> = $a^2(E[X^2]-E[X]^2)$
>
> = $a^2 Var(X)$

My book does like three lines and they start out with $Var(aX + b) = E[(aX + b - (a\mu + b) ) ^2]$. I don't understand why they substract $(a\mu + b)$ instead of $\mu$ because $Var(X) = E[(X - \mu)^2]$

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, they subtract $a\mu + b$ because that is the mean of $Y$. Every time you find the variance of a random variable from the definition, you need to subtract its mean in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $E[Y] = E[aX + b] = aE[X] + b = a\mu + b$.

Comment: Yeah I know, I used that fact for my second line of proof

Comment: And what you're trying to find is $Var(Y)$, not $Var(X)$.

Comment: Yeah and I got my result to be a^2 Var(X)

Comment: I am not sure if you feel that I answered your question or not. I basically said the same thing as Ken Dunn. You asked why they subtract $a\mu + b$ instead of $\mu$. My answer is because you're computing $Var(Y)$, and $E[Y] = a\mu + b$.

Comment: Is my alternative proof correct though?

Comment: Sorry for super slow response, but yeah, your alternative proof is correct too. It's just a little more tedious.